# Compute $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow -3} \frac{\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{x}}{3+x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow -3} \frac{\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{x}}{3+x}$$

Can I multiply the top and bottom by $3x$? If not, why not. I am having a hard time understanding when it is appropriate to multiply the numerator and denominator by the LCD.

Comment: Yes you can. The answer will be $\frac{-1}{9}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

\begin{align*}\lim_{x\rightarrow -3}\ \frac{\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{x}}{3+x} & = \lim_{x\rightarrow -3}\ \frac{x+3}{3x(3+x)} \\&= \lim_{x\rightarrow -3}\ \frac{1}{3x} = \frac{-1}{9}\end{align*}

Comment: So I should not multiply lets say 3x into anything other than 1? Is there a better way to indicate this rule.

Comment: In calculus book, we call it "canceling a common factor" Note that in problem, denomintor is $x+3=0$ So if $x\neq -3$, we make a "simpler fraction" so that we have $$ \frac{1}{3x}$$.

Answer (score 2):

You can multiply the top and bottom of a fraction by anything you like, as long as it is not zero.  In this case you are investigating a limit as $x\to-3$, so it is valid to assume $x\ne0$ and therefore $3x\ne0$.

Comment: I guess my question is when I find the lcd, is there a rule when it comes to creating products? I had previously mutiplied 3x by (3+x), thus 9+3x^2.

Comment: Multiplying top and bottom by $3x(3+x)$ would not be wrong but you would just be creating extra work for yourself.

Comment: EThe point is to perform an algebraic simplification that allows you to cancel the obstructive factor. You are just combining the two fractions in the numerator.